# AWS function policy is bigger than the limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an Amazon API gateway linking to AWS java Lambda back end. 
I am trying to add a new Method to a Resource and I get the following error when choosing the integration point for the new method.

The error is:

**" The function policy is bigger than the limit. Please manually update policy via lambda cli."**

How do I go about updating the policy and why is this error occurring ?

Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: Related: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=716202

Comment: I did see that but I have no idea what this really means. I was hoping for a better explanation. I have only every used AWS via the GUI/Webpage.

Comment: Policy documents in AWS typically have a size limit. You need to look for ways to shrink the document.

Comment: Does that not just limit the number of endpoints (Resources) you can have on an API ?

Comment: According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_AddPermission.html, the Lambda function access policy is limited to 20KB. Perhaps you can use GetPolicy to retrieve the existing policy and review it for opportunities to simplify it.

Comment: I have like 3 more endpoints ,,,anyway to increase the document size ? I can get the policy but no idea where to start.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150658/discussion-between-jarmod-and-devilcode).

Comment: jarmod - i created a new API to test and linking it to the same lambda backend provides the same issue. Its a policy document held in lambda somewhere i guess. Everything is now offline =(

Answer (score 0):

Ok as suggested the issue is with a 20kb limit with the Policy document. You can get the policy document via the Cli though for me it didn't help much as unless there is a way to overwrite it and a way to optimise it then its pretty useless. That said there may be I couldn't find it.

Note this is a Lambda issue in this case not a API Gateway one. In short I had a lot of endpoints (~30/50) which for an API is nothing in the wild however each endpoint needs a relevant few lines in the policy document where its linking the Lambda Code to the API Gateway endpoint. at around 30 to 50 endpoints this fills the Policy document.

There may be better ways to do this .... but at that limit even when I deleted a few unused endpoints it didn't help. The solution was to delete the Lambda Function code and remake it.

However this will only clear the Policy document until you recreate the links again. In order to avoid this problem occurring again I had to reduce the endpoints to the core ones then use a passed parameter to trigger the correct code within Lambda.

```
    Instead of  https://www.something.com/cars/iswindowopen
    do
    Instead of  https://www.something.com/cars
    {
     "call":"iswindowopen"
    }
```

In sort pass the many endpoints as a parameter. This was porbably my fault for not reading enough of the documentation but this limit is well hidden in my opinion so watch out =)

Answer (score 0):

If you use python, you can use the Boto3 lambda API get_policy to see what resource-based policies are attached with your lambda functions and then use remove_permission to clean up duplicate policies or policies that aren't needed. You can also use AWS Lambda CLI get-policy and remove-permission to inspect and clean up your policies.
You can check out [this article](https://link.medium.com/GNpSsG4JPX) for information on how to fix this issue.

After you fix this issue, you should [configure the permission for your API](https://link.medium.com/RAvxqRN4OX) to invoke Lambda using a resource based policy or an IAM role to prevent getting this error in the future.